# import axios in another js file

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, axios

It's a flask based project, and I'd like to import axios into another js file.

in my figuresHelper.js, I'd like to import axios to fetch data from api service

```
import {PieChart} from './pie-chart-module.js'
import * as axios from './axios.js'

let figuresHelper = {
    init: function(){ console.log('init something'); axios.get('url').... }
}
export {figuresHelper}
```

and the code in my index.html

```
<script type="module">
    import {figuresHelper} from "../static/js/figuresHelper.js";
    figuresHelper.init()
</script>
```

it raises error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'axios' of undefined
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition
```

I'm not allowed to use vue in this project so far and this problem kills me

Comment: are you using any build system like webpack?

Answer (score 1):

you can't just

```
export const figuresHelper = () => {
    console.log('init something'); 
    axios.get('url')....
}
```

then in html?

```
<script type="module">
    import {figuresHelper} from "../static/js/figuresHelper.js";
    figuresHelper();
</script>
```

Comment: the import of axios causes trouble not the figureHelper. My purpose is to import axios into the helper so I will be able to use the interceptor